# Protect phototransistor from emitter-collector breakdown

Tags: protection, phototransistor, reverse-breakdown

I'm using the ADC on the reset pin on an ATTiny85 to detect an IR level. The reset pin is disabled in the fuses but I would like the ability to "recover" the fuses and reprogram the device.

The emitter-collector breakdown voltage of the phototransistor is minimum 5V. During programming, 12V will be applied to the emitter. The collector will either be at 0V or 5V depending on the state of another pin during programming. Best case, there will be 7V from emitter to collector. Worst case, there will be 12V from emitter to collector. Both of these will result in the destruction of the transistor. The schematic below shows this in a much clearer way.

How can I protect the phototransistor against breakdown?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd9CPL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Link to datasheet?

Comment: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/220962/BRIGHT/BPT-BP2931.html

Comment: Reprogramming isn't supposed to happen often? Just disconnect it with a jumper.

Comment: Unfortunately board space it at a premium. The widget is only 25mm by 35mm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider adding a diode as shown below:

[image]

This approach can be made to work in particular if the IR level sensing you are doing is "digital" in nature. The lower drop of a BAT54 may be desirable.

If you are trying to actually measure analogue variation of the IR signal a more complex circuit may be required.

Comment: If I add a diode, the transistor will still be reversed biased with 12V but the reverse leakage of the diode will be too small to damage the transistor?

Comment: @bitshift - Actually the diode will also be reversed biased. If you pick a diode with a 50V or 60V reverse voltage rating it's leakage current will be rather lower at 12V. The leakage current that could flow will also be going through the transistor. Each component will exhibit an equivalent resistance at that leakage current which will end up determining how the total 12V reverse bias divides between the two components. If you have concern about that you could add a bleeder resistor from the transistor emitter to GND of 10K or 22K or 33K ohms to shunt the diode leakage to GND.